# UIRefreshControl pull-UP to refresh?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uirefreshcontrol

I hooked up a NSFetchedResultController with a UITableViewController.

I would love to implement UIRefreshControl at the BOTTOM of my UITableView. This means that my users will be scrolling down to the bottom of the table. Then the user will scroll up to trigger UIRefreshControl.

Can this be done? I am not able to Google anything on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  `UITableViewController` automatically positions the `UIRefreshControl` at the top of the tableView's content.  If you'd like to be able to do this, I'd suggest filing [an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com) asking for it.

Also, couldn't you just detect that you're getting near the bottom of the table and refresh automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [CCBottomRefreshControl](https://github.com/vlasov/CCBottomRefreshControl) category for UIScrollView class (parent of UITableView and UICollectionView classes) that implements **bottomRefreshControl** property. I'm sure that's what you're looking for.